# Creating menu folder under Resources stops Xamarin from reloading Resource.designer.cs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I had an issue in my project with Resource.designer.cs. At some point it stopped refreshing. I've tried every solution on the internet with no success. I decided to create a fresh Android application project. Few hours later I figured out that when I add "menu" folder under "Resources" Resource.designer.cs stops reloading. When I remove it, everything is back to normal.

Is there anyone struggling with same problem or someone who could probably try to reproduce it and give his insight? It's as simple as starting new android app project, adding menu folder under resources, adding xml file in created menu folder and trying to use it by typing Resource.Menu.[xml file name from menu folder] in MainActivity.

For a record, I've checked it on MacOS with newest stable version of xamarin studio and visual studio community with same result.

Comment: What are the contents of the xml file that you are adding? (if the resource designer file is not generating it usually means that you have an error within one of your resources files)

Comment: @SushiHangover I left it with the pre generated line: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I left it with the pre generated line: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?

By creating a menu resource that has no valid menu elements, you are going to get the following build error:

`Error APT0000:  Error parsing XML: no element found (APT0000)`

Finish adding your (valid) menu elements to the menu file and the `Resource.designer.cs` will be updated.

Comment: You were right. After adding some content it is working fine now.